# How to delete multiple rows using checkbox in Laravel 5.5 + Vue.js + Axios

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to implement a deletion of multiple items using checkbox. I am using Laravel 5.5, Vue.js and Bulma's component - Buefy + Axios.

My Vue.js Component:

```
<template>
<section>
    <button class="button field is-small is-danger" @click="checkedRows = []"
        :disabled="!checkedRows.length">
        <b-icon icon="close"></b-icon>
        <span>Clear checked</span>
    </button>
    <button class="is-small button is-danger" @click.prevent="onDelete" title="Delete checked" :disabled="!checkedRows.length"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>

    <b-field grouped group-multiline>                      
        <b-select v-model="perPage" :disabled="!isPaginated" size="is-small">
            <option value="5">5 per page</option>
            <option value="10">10 per page</option>
            <option value="15">15 per page</option>
            <option value="20">20 per page</option>
        </b-select>
        <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-small" @click="currentPage = 2" :disabled="!isPaginated">Set page to 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="control is-flex">
            <b-switch v-model="isPaginated" size="is-small">Paginated</b-switch>
        </div>
        <div class="control is-flex">
            <b-switch v-model="isPaginationSimple" :disabled="!isPaginated" size="is-small">Simple pagination</b-switch>
        </div>
    </b-field>

    <b-table
        :data="enquiries"
        :paginated="isPaginated"
        :per-page="perPage"
        :current-page.sync="currentPage"
        :pagination-simple="isPaginationSimple"
        :default-sort-direction="defaultSortDirection"
        default-sort="created_at"
        :checked-rows.sync="checkedRows"
        :is-row-checkable="(row) => row.id !== 3"
        checkable>

        <template slot-scope="props">
            <b-table-column field="id" label="ID" width="40" sortable numeric>
                <small>{{ props.row.id }}</small>
            </b-table-column>

            <b-table-column field="date" label="Registration date" sortable centered>
                <span class="tag is-success">
                    {{ new Date(props.row.created_at).toLocaleDateString() }}
                </span>
            </b-table-column>

            <b-table-column field="company" label="Company" sortable>
                <small>{{ props.row.company }}</small>
            </b-table-column>

            <b-table-column field="first_name" label="First Name" sortable>
                <small>{{ props.row.first_name }}</small>
            </b-table-column>

            <b-table-column field="last_name" label="Last Name" sortable>
                <small>{{ props.row.last_name }}</small>
            </b-table-column>   

            <b-table-column field="email" label="Email" sortable>
                <small>{{ props.row.email }}</small>
            </b-table-column> 

            <b-table-column field="phone" label="Phone" sortable>
                <small>{{ props.row.phone }}</small>
            </b-table-column> 

        </template>
    </b-table>
</section>
```

```
<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {                      
            enquiries: [],
            errors: [],
            isPaginated: true,
            isPaginationSimple: false,
            defaultSortDirection: 'asc',
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 5,
            checkedRows: []

        }
    },       

    created() {
        axios.get('/manage/demo-enquiries')
             .then(response => {
                this.enquiries = response.data  
             })
             .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
             })
    }, 

    methods: {
        onDelete() {
            axios.delete('/manage/demo-enquiries', {params: {'id': 
                this.checkedRows}})
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response)
                }, (error) => {
                    // error callback
            })
        }
    }       
}
```

Route:

`Route::delete('manage/demo-enquiries/', 'DemorequestController@destroy');`

And Controller:

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    try 
    {
        Demorequest::whereIn('id', $request->id)->delete(); // $request->id MUST be an array
        return response()->json('Enquiry deleted');
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
}
```

When I select several rows and click delete, the browser console says "{data: "Enquiry deleted", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}" but nothing gets removed from the DB.

Can anyone please help find a solution to multi deletion using checkbox?

Comment: have you checked if the array is passed correctly in the request?

Comment: hmmm....I dont think it does....my request URL is /demo-enquiries?id[]=%7B%22id%22:40,%22first_name%22:%22Anton%22,%22last_name%22:%22Sirik%22,%22email%22:%22anton.sirik@i-nexus.com%22,%22job_title%22:%22Marketing+Executive%22,%22company%22:%22i- and so on and on

Comment: What's the output of the `$request` object?

Comment: the request object is `null` from the url above, which means the problem is your not passing any id, can you check if that array has any data in vue devtools

Comment: @Jackowski, I believe this is what goes through on request: id[]: {"id":39,"first_name":"Anton","last_name":"Sirik","email":"anton.sirik@i-nexus.com","job_title":"Marketing","company":"i-nexus","phone":"+447507633865","consent":"1","created_at":"2018-04-18 13:35:41","updated_at":"2018-04-18 13:35:41"}
id[]: {"id":40,"first_name":"Anton","last_name":"Sirik","email":"anton.sirik@i-nexus.com","job_title":"Marketing Executive","company":"i-nexus","phone":"+447507633865","consent":"1","created_at":"2018-04-18 13:37:29","updated_at":"2018-04-18 13:37:29"}

Comment: @jafar690 here is what gets checked in VUE https://snag.gy/59KiMV.jpg

Comment: I believe the problem here is that you're passing an array with objects when you only want an array with ids. Ex: `[39, 40]`

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea how to only get ids from checkedRows. this.checkedRows.id - does not work, I get Undefined id in the console when I do this.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to extract the `id` from the object array using `array_column()`

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    try 
    {
        $ids = array_column($request->id, "id");
        Demorequest::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete(); 
        return response()->json('Enquiry deleted');
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
}
```

Also, another way to do it without touching the php code is getting only the id from the checkboxes.

`this.checkedRows.map(a=>a.id)`

Comment: I get 405 Method Not Allowed :(

Comment: @AntonSirik change `Route::delete('manage/demo-enquiries/', 'DemorequestController@destroy')`  to `Route::get('manage/demo-enquiries/', 'DemorequestController@destroy')`

Comment: the checked rows array gets passed instead of ids

Comment: still get 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: DELETE /manage/demo-enquiry?id[]=40&id[]=39&id[]=38&id[]=37&id[]=36 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: either change back to `Route::delete` or set the axios as a get call `axios.get`